# Get url from NetworkImageView

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have a ListView populated where one of the items in each row is a NetworkImageView. Now I´m passing each row by Intent putExtra() to a detail_product activity.

With TextViews I've being doing:

```
String pName = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();
...
i.putExtra(TAG_NAME, pName);
```

How to proceed with NetworkImageView? I can't use `getText` or `getResources()`.

**EDIT**

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (inflater == null)
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null)
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

    if (imageLoader == null)
        imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
    NetworkImageView thumbNail = (NetworkImageView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);

    TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);


    Product m = productItems.get(position);

    // thumbnail image
    String url = m.getThumbnailUrl();
    thumbNail.setImageUrl(url, imageLoader);
    thumbNail.setTag(url);

    // name
    name.setText(m.getName());



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No getter available for NetworkImageView that provides you URL set to it.

One way is to use tags for your NetworkImageView. You could set your image URL as tag for your NetworkImageView.For eg. holder.thumbNail.setTag(imgUrl) inside your getView(...) of Adapter for ListView.

In your onItemClick listener for ListView

```
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        NetworkImageView v = (NetworkImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        String imgUrl = (String) v.getTag();
```

Another way could be through Reflection [please avoid, as you could see I referred to "mUrl", a private variable used inside NetworkImageView and very likely to change at any point of time]

```
    Class nw = NetworkImageView.class;
    try {
        Field url=nw.getDeclaredField("mUrl");
        url.setAccessible(true);
        String imgUrl=(String) url.get(your_networkview_object);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: should I change my setImageUrl? code: " thumbNail.setImageUrl(m.getThumbnailUrl(), imageLoader); " where "m" comes from "Product m = productItems.get(position);

Comment: No, you would need to bind request image URL to your NetworkImageView. 
      String url=m.getThumbnailUrl();
      holder.thumbNail.setImageUrl(url, imageLoader);
      holder.thumbNail.setTag(url);

Comment: please, take a look at EDIT to tell me if the code is right

Comment: Relevant code looks good to me! If you could use ViewHolder  in getView(...) it would be great

Comment: It would have to create a new class ViewHolder!? Could you help me with detail_product activity? Can I pass this url from a NetworkImageView to an ImageView? I tried to use BitmapFactory but image did not appear.

Comment: For ViewHolder pattern, you can refer to https://www.codeofaninja.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html . I'm not sure what did you try with BitmapFactory, but why do you need an ImageView? NetworkImageView should be good enough even in detail_product since if your image was downloaded in list screen, your singleton ImageLoader should already have the image with it. So if you call say detailThumnail.setImageUrl(url_passed_in_extra, imageLoader) will load previously downloaded image only.

Comment: It works fine! I´ll study ViewHolder and how to open image big clicking on it. Thank you so much!